# Python: how to insert new column while trying to strip white spaces

Tags: python, dataframe, strip

I have a data frame in jupyter (it was imported from a excel file).
Example say column B has `"    tony "`.

I want to insert a new column into my data frame in index 0 that will replicate that same column B but remove the white spaces (with strip?). Like in excel `=TRIM (A1)`. <--I need to do this in my new column.

I know this is wrong but here is what I am trying to do 
`bd.insert(0, 'POL_ID_LOOKUP', bd.policy.strip() )`

Comment: `bd.insert(0,'POL_ID_LOOKUP',bd['policy'].str.strip())`

Comment: that worked! thank you.  why do you have [ ] around policy? Also why are you using .str?

Comment: There are two ways to access columns. One is with brackets and one is as an attribute as you have done. It is generally preferred to use brackets as there could be collisions with built-in attributes.

Comment: Here's the documentation for `.str`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html